# What are some methods that UX testers use in order to test out websites?

Tags: html, debugging, testing, user-experience, stress-testing

I am curious how actual professional UX/QA testers test websites out. The reason why I ask is I have been assigned to stress-test and "break" our website for our school project, but really don't know if there's methodical ways of going about so. I've created an windows form app in the past, and when we tested it I basically just clicked on everything we created or input strings or integers into fields to try and break our algorithm, but I feel like perhaps it's different this time with our website. As an analogy, it's almost as if I'm trying to create UML-related flowcharts and diagrams, but not adhering to the UML flowchart and diagram rules, processes and the definitions of each shape.

So aside from manually going into our website and just clicking on stuff, adding values into our prompts or input fields and what not, are there actual software programs I can run that automate these sort of things? I stopped and browsed several related existing threads pertaining to the same topic, but they mention more about fundamental ways about testing. I'm looking for more specific things and possibly software I can use to help stress test our website. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different types of testing that can occur for a website.  Usually, QA testers run very different types of tests than those who are testing the user experience in some way.

QA testers usually engage in both black box testing and white box testing.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402161/black-box-vs-white-box-testing) is a pretty good overview of the difference between black box and white box testing.  In terms of applications, [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org) is an excellent one; you might find other test frameworks more of use to you, depending on what technologies your website is using.

User experience testers consider what real-world users will do with the website.  I wouldn't consider it a part of stress testing.  I'm including it in my answer because it's part of the title of your question.  In a standard [usability test](http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/usability-testing.html), you ask real users (or people who are representative of your intended real users) to complete a small handful of tasks while you observe what they do.  The goal is not to find functional errors in the website (although you might find some during the course of your usability test), but rather to determine whether your users are able to complete their goals using your site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for e2e (end to end) testing: there are different libraries that use softwares like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to run automated tasks on the browser. You can have a look to [Protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) or [Nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/).

There is also another interesting kind of tests, [perceptual testing](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/perceptual-testing), that we (my company) are implementing recently: you can create some *accepted* screenshots of your web application and an automated task checks if every pixel is in the right place and, if not, it gives you a png with all the differences.